# Div Layout changes with mobile browser

Tags: css, layout, html, mobile

When viewed by Chrome, Safari, FireFox & IE this looks fine.

When viewed landscape on Mobile Android phone it looks fine, view it portrait and the list overlaps the bottom of the container.

Why and how do I fix it ?

```
<style>
div.test {color:black; text-align:left; border-radius:15px; -moz-border-radius:15px; border:2px solid #000; background-color:#808080; }
ul#navlist {width:80%; \width:80%; w\idth:80%; padding:15px; border-top:0px; margin:0px; color:#ffffff; font:10pt verdana,helvetica,arial,sans-serif; }
ul#navlist li {list-style:none; }
ul#navlist li a {display:block; padding:4px 8px 4px 8px; border-left:20px solid #808080; background:#808080; text-decoration:none; text-align:left; font:bold 10pt verdana,helvetica,arial,sans-serif; }
ul#navlist li a:link {color:#fff; }
div#nav li a:visited {color:#fff; }
ul#navlist li a:hover {border-color:#fff; color:#ffffff; background:#202020; }
</style>

<div class="test" style="position:absolute; top:30px; left:10px; width:485px; height:580px">
<div id="nav" ><ul id="navlist"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;DEMO</b>
<li><a href="#">TEST Entry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TEST Entry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TEST Entry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TEST Entry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TEST Entry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TEST Entry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TEST Entry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TEST Entry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TEST Entry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TEST Entry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TEST Entry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TEST Entry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TEST Entry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TEST Entry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TEST Entry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TEST Entry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TEST Entry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TEST Entry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TEST Entry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TEST Entry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TEST Entry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TEST Entry</a></li>
</ul></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write 2 css 1 for Landscape and 1 for portrait and just copy paste the below code and it will be working fine
meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

```
meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:portrait)" href="../../../css/potrait.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:landscape)" href="../../../css/landscape.css" />
```

Comment: Never thought of that !
Thanks